# How to create a button and attach an event to it using jQuery? - HTML5+jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, button

I am trying to make an HTML5 space shooter game, and when the player loses, a continue button should be created. I am actually using canvas to draw a rectangle and add an event listener to it:

```
  if (!alive) {
  ctx.fillText('Game Over!', 245, height / 2);
  ctx.fillText('Lost times:'+lostTimes, 245, height / 2+100);
  ctx.fillRect((width / 2) - 53, (height / 2) + 10,100,40);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
  ctx.fillText('Continue?', 252, (height / 2) + 35);
  canvas.addEventListener('click', continueButton, false);
  }
```

But I want to use jQuery instead. I checked the jQuery documents, but everything about button there is to add events to an HTML element which already exists in the HTML file. What I need is to dynamically create the button when a certain condition is met(alive==false in this case), and I also have to indicate the place of the button. Anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: look at the Manipulation / DOM insertion category in jQuery API. Many mehtods for adding html to page. Also look at `on()` to add clcik handler for elements that don't exist yet

Comment: @phil  either way will work. Adding html is easy to understand from API category I pointed you to and there are plenty of examples as well. Hiding and showing html is even easier, look at `hide()` and `show()`

Comment: @charlietfl Alright, thank you for your help anyway.

Comment: It's easy, once you've got a canvas, to be drawn into doing everything with SVG, but peripheral HTML controls should always remain an option, at least in development when you are likely to change your mind every half hour. If ultimately you feel the controls should be more "part of the game" then migrate some or all onto the canvas. With well-structured code the migration should be almost painless.

Comment: BTW, @charlietfl is one of the good guys round here and well worth listening to.